# C# - Count string length and replace each character with another

Tags: c#, string, replace, character

How can I count the number of characters within a string and create another string with the same number of characters but replace all of them with a single character such as "*"?  Thank you.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
string newString = new string('*', oldString.Length);
```

Of course, it this is for displaying password equivalents, it might be better to use a fixed number of asterisks - the less clues the better. Of course, since you'd **obviously** be *hashing* the password (with salt) and storing just the hash, you couldn't know the actual length anyway ;-p

Comment: A fixed number of asterisks makes no sense for a password input field. If you're going to give the user no feedback whatsoever, then you might as well not display anything at all.

Comment: @Joren There are of course cases where you would use a fixed number of asteriks to not giving a hacker the information how long the password is.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be:

```
Console.Write(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("test",".", "*"));
```

Comment: From a performance perspective, it would be extremely unwise to create a Regex object for a purpose such as this.  The above string methods would be more performant.

Comment: yah, I know but it seems the question didn't ask for any perfomance hit.

Comment: Please back up "from a performance perspective ... unwise to create a Regex object". While it may not be an ideal solution here, this smells like a bad case of "premature optimization guessing".

Comment: OK, happy to cater for your opinions re. "premature optimization guessing".  However, my comment about not being a good idea to create a regex parser for this (over the other solutions) stands.

Comment: What if the pattern was cached?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach -  anything involving Regex is slower than the string length-and-new technique. NOTE: Regex doc says caching happens automatically for "static methods of Regex" (eg. `Regex.somemethod`).

Answer (score 0):

```
var message = "hello world" ;
var newMessage = new String('*', message.Length);
```